# Getting PHP5 To install

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd, yum, centos5

It seems I am stuck with a 4yo build of PHP (PHP4.3.9 Built: 2007) and I am trying to upgrade. Right now, it's like a traffic puzzle, or a vicious cycle, whatever you want to call it. I try to upgrade PHP, but it depends on a newer httpd-mmn, so I try upgrading apr (apache/httpd) or installing a newer RPM of httpd, trying the RPM just says its the version i'm running (ya right) and upgrading apr has more dependencies, resulting in YUM trying to satisfy the dependencies for the new HTTPD it wants to install, but it has dependencies, apparently, in the new apr -.-. I can't really get out of this, rut, and would greatly appreciate help :).

[Here is an example of trying to update apr and PHP](http://hargrave.tk/debugs/yumapr.txt)

Comment: woop! need to add 1 thing to the log

Comment: added bit of code.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the simplest approach would be to upgrade the entire installation - which is generally good practice anyway. However having been caught in a trap due to closed source drivers (thanks Intel) I know that's not always a practical solution.

Have you considered compiling from source? [Old versions of PHP](http://php.net/releases/index.php) are available back to 3.0. You'll need to install the dev packages for the dependant stuff you've already got installed - and don't forget to remove the PHP rpms before **installing** your compiled PHP (to avoid the package amanger overwriting your compiled code). NB make sure you can compile the PHP first!

Comment: Could you define "entire installation?", are you referring to centOS and everything, or apache and its components. I will see about trying this.

Comment: Yes - upgrade OS, webserver, php